# how to continue uinavigationcontroller pattern using uisegmentedcontrol

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

[image: my segmented storyboard image]

I am having trouble deciding on the optimal design which will cause the least amount of trouble along the coding period of my project.

I have two separate storyboards; one for the login rituals and the other one involving the main flow of the application.

The part i need your valuable suggestions is the main storyboard.

In main storyboard, There will be a homeScreenVC (rootVC of navigationVC) which has a uisegmentedcontrol in its navigationItem. When segmented items are pressed, the containerView of homeScreenVC is replaced by the corresponding VC's view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    firstVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstsid"];
    secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondsid"];

    [self.view addSubview:firstVC.view];
    [self.view addSubview:SecondVC.view];
}
```

lets call these views, firstVC and secondVC.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:secondVC.view];
```

There is no problem up to this point.

What i can not figure out in this current scenario is that when user presses on a button in firstVC and childOfFirstVC needs to be pushed, the app crashes saying that the parent needs to be an instance of an UINavigationViewController.

the container homeScreenVC is an instance of UINavigationViewController. But it seems firstVC, which is contained in homeScreenVC, is not an instance of UINavigationViewController.

How can i continue navigation even after using VCs contained in segmented controls?

How would you set your design? SHould firstVC and secondVC be uinavigationcontrollers as well? If YES, would having multiple navcontrollers be a problem in the future?

Important: the future overall design would have much more child VCs and be branched out more. And i would be needing to navigate from a child view of firstVC to a childview of secondVC and vice versa.

I tried to add a screenshot in case visualizing what i wrote was difficult.

Thank you,

Aytunc

Comment: You might want to add some code especially on how do you push VC from one to another.

Comment: @sha Thanks for the quick reply, Are you talking about pushing the childoffirstVC? if yes, as for now, i just put a uibutton on firstVC and ctrl+dragged it on to childoffirstVC and chose push as the segue method. I am open to other methods for pushing as well.

Comment: @rdelmar I know, and i only need help on this storyboard. Actually, mentioning about 2 storyboards were not necessary. i thought maybe people would like to criticize that design choice as well. but it has nothing to do with my problem. sorry for the confusion:(

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but adding the view of one controller to the view of another is not a good thing to do, unless you make that second controller a child view controller of the second. That still wouldn't fix your crash problem though. Do you need to see that segmented control though the whole app? IF you have two separate paths (starting at firstVC and secondVC) why not use a tab bar controller where those controllers (each embedded in its own navigation controllers) would be two of the tabs?

Comment: @rdelmar using a tabbarcontroller instead of a segmentedcontrol is not an option for me because of two things: first i want the segments/tabs on the top, integrated in the navcontroller (so that it doesnt eat extra space in the window) and secondly, i only want to see the segments only in the HomeScreenVC and NOT in childviews. Can u explain why adding the view of VC to another VC's view is a bad idea? thank you

Comment: If you don't add the controller as a child, events (like rotations) aren't properly sent to that controller. You should read Apple's "Implementing a Custom Container View Controller" document. As to your structure, Maybe you can just hook a push segue up to each of the segments of the segmented control to go to the first and second controllers, instead of adding them as children. You should have a 3 segment control though, and have the first one be the home screen, so you see that controller first, and have to select one of the other segments to go to the next controller.